# Подключение к серверу по RCON

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Объясните, почему этот код возвращает нужный результат:

```
import socket

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.connect(("192.168.0.101", 28960))
    sock.send(b"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFrcon xxxxxxxxx status")
    print (sock.recv(65565))
    sock.close()
```

вывод

> `b'\xff\xff\xff\xffprint\nmap:mp_rust\nnum score ping guid name lastmsg address qport rate\n`
>
> `--- ----- ----  -------------------------------- --------------- ------- --------------------- ----- -----\n\n\x00'`

а этот постоянно, при любой команде, возвращает

> `b'\xff\xff\xff\xffdisconnect\x00'`

test.py

```
import socket
from models import RconConnection

if __name__ == "__main__":
connection = RconConnection("192.168.0.101", 28960)
connection.connect()
connection.auth("xxxxxxxx")
connection.send("status")
print(connection.response(128))
```

models.py

```
import socket

class RconConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    def connect(self):
        self.socket.connect(("%s" % (self.ip), self.port))
        return 1

    def auth(self, password):
        string = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFrcon_password %s" % (password)
        self.socket.send(bytearray(string, "utf-8"))
        return 1

    def send(self, command):
        string = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFrcon %s" % (command)
        self.socket.send(bytearray(string, "utf-8"))
        return 1

    def response(self, size):
        string = self.socket.recv(size)
        return string
```

Comment: Не знаток питона, но что-то мне подсказывает, что вместо 

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)


надо что-то вроде


    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Comment: Нет, проблема точно не в этом, потому что первый пример отрабатывает как и ожидается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Проблема была в том, что при `.encode()` строка `b"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFrcon xxxxxxxxx status"` превращалась в `b'\xc3\xbf\xc3\xbf\xc3\xbf\xc3\xbfrcon xxxxxxxxx serverinfo'` и сервер не принимал такое начало пакета